# how to list mysql query result in particular sequence?

Tags: mysql

the problem #14 from SQLZoo 
for table
  nobel(yr, subject, winner)
goes as
  "Show the 1984 winners and subject ordered by subject and winner name; but list Chemistry and Physics last."

my solution is

```
SELECT winner, subject
  FROM nobel
 WHERE yr=1984 
 ORDER BY subject,winner
```

but it does not list chemistry and physics at last.
is there a way to do so?
and how to order a field in particular sequence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use can use`CASE`:

```
SELECT winner, subject
FROM nobel
WHERE yr=1984 
ORDER BY
 CASE
    WHEN subject IN ('Physics','Chemistry') THEN 1
    ELSE 0
 END ASC,
 subject,
 winner
```

**EDIT:**

This is primary the same as [Gordon Linoff Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32934151/5070879), but can be extended to another subjects if needed using more rules. `IN` allows only 2 ways: false/true.

```
ORDER BY
 CASE
    WHEN subject IN ('Physics','Chemistry') THEN 2
    WHEN subject IN ('Medicine','Literature') THEN 1
    ELSE 0
 END ASC,
 subject,
 winner
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add additional keys into the `order by`.  For this particular purpose:

```
order by (subject in ('Chemistry', 'Physics') ),
         subject, winner
```

The first condition is a boolean expression that evaluates to either 1 (for true) or 0 (for false).  Hence, the falses appear before the trues.

Comment: but how do we make sure that false appear before trues? shouldn't we use subject not in ("chemistry", "physics")

Comment: @SHRIKANTDANGI . . . That is what this `order by` does.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT winner, subject 
FROM nobel 
WHERE yr = 1984 
ORDER BY subject IN ('Chemistry', 'Physics'), subject, winner
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select subject, winner,yr
from nobel
where yr=1984
order by subject in ('Chemistry','Physics'),subject,winner
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT winner, subject
  FROM nobel
 WHERE yr=1984
 ORDER BY 
   case when subject IN ('Physics','Chemistry') then 0
         ELSE 1 
END desc,subject,winner
```